# serial communication in android device java

Tags: java, android

**Serial communication between android and Hardware Device**

i tried to develop application that support communication between the android device and the hardware it is possible to develop app like that ?
no different any language java or C#

Answer (score 0):

You should look into ADB for that:
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

EDIT: Or do you mean letting the Android device communicate with other Android devices? Could you clarify your question?